# How to write a file from an ArrayBuffer in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, meteor, arraybuffer

I am trying to write a file uploader for Meteor framework.
The principle is to split the fileon the client from an ArrayBuffer in small packets of 4096 bits that are sent to the server through a Meteor.method.

The *simplified* code below is the part of the client that sends a chunk to the server, it is repeated until **offset** reaches **data.byteLength** :

```
// data is an ArrayBuffer
var total = data.byteLength;
var offset = 0;

var upload = function() {
  var length = 4096; // chunk size

  // adjust the last chunk size
  if (offset + length > total) {
     length = total - offset;
  }

  // I am using Uint8Array to create the chunk
  // because it can be passed to the Meteor.method natively
  var chunk = new Uint8Array(data, offset, length);

  if (offset < total) {
     // Send the chunk to the server and tell it what file to append to
     Meteor.call('uploadFileData', fileId, chunk, function (err, length) {
        if (!err) {
          offset += length;
          upload();
        }
     }
  }
};
upload(); // start uploading
```

The *simplified* code below is the part on the server that receives the chunk and writes it to the file system :

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
  uploadFileData: function(fileId, chunk) {
    var fut = new Future();
    var path = '/uploads/' + fileId;

    // I tried that with no success
    chunk = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, chunk);

    // how to write the chunk that is an Uint8Array to the disk ?
    fs.appendFile(path, chunk, 'binary', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        fut.throw(err);
      } else {
        fut.return(chunk.length);
      }
    });
    return fut.wait();
  }
});
```

I failed to write a valid file to the disk, actually the file is saved but I cannot open it, when I see the content in a text editor, it is similar to the original file (a jpg for example) but some characters are different, I think that could be an encoding problem as the file size is not the same, but I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: can you pass a blob instead? they usually come out in node as Buffers, which fs.AppendFile()  handles.

Comment: @dandavis Actually you gave me the half of the answer, see the solution was simple after all, Thank you !

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Saving the file was as easy as creating a new Buffer with the Uint8Array object :

```
// chunk is the Uint8Array object
fs.appendFile(path, Buffer.from(chunk), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      fut.throw(err);
    } else {
      fut.return(chunk.length);
    }
});
```

Comment: new Buffer(chunk) is deprecated use Buffer.from(chunk)

Answer (score 31):

Building on [Karl.S answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31583876/1193155), this worked for me, outside of any framework:

```
fs.appendFileSync(outfile, Buffer.from(arrayBuffer));
```

Comment: new Buffer is deprecated. Use Buffer.from(arrayBuffer) instead.

Comment: Using synchronous version of I/O functions is not recommended since it block the event loop, unless you have a reason to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that in newer Meteor you could avoid some callback hell with `async/await`. Await will also throw and push the error up to client

```
Meteor.methods({
  uploadFileData: async function(file_id, chunk) {
    var path = 'somepath/' + file_id; // be careful with this, make sure to sanitize file_id
    await fs.appendFile(path, new Buffer(chunk));
    return chunk.length;
  }
});
```